# Multiple updates performance improvement

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have built an application with Spring Boot and JPA to migrate a Jira postgres database.

Basically, I have 5000 users that I need to migrate. Each user means 67 update queries in different tables.

Each query uses the LOWER function to compare ignoring case.

Some pseudo-code:

```java
for (user : users){
  for (query : queries) {
    jdbcTemplate.execute(query.replace(user....
```

I ignore any errors, so if a single query fails, I still go on and execute the other 66.

I am running this in 10 separate threads and each user is taking roughly 120 seconds to migrate. (20 threads resulted in database dead lock)

At this pace, it's gonna take more than a day, which is not acceptable (I am running this in a test environment before doing in production).

The queries looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE table SET column = 'NEWUSERNAME' where LOWER(column) = LOWER('CURRENTUSERNAME');
```

Is there anything I can do to try and optimize this migration?

UPDATE:
I changed my approach. First, I select every element with the CURRENTUSERNAME and get it's ID. Then I create the UPDATE queries using the ID as the "where" clause.

Other than that, it is still taking a long time (4+ hours) to execute.
I am running millions of UPDATEs, each at a time. I know jdbcTemplate has a bulk method, but if a single UPDATE fails, I believe it roll's back every successful update too. Also, I am not aware of the performance improvement it would have, if any.

So, to update the question, given that I have millions of UPDATE queries to run, what would be the best way execute them? (bulk, multi threading, something else)

Comment: Maybe jdbcTemplate's [batchUpdate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter-) would help ?

Comment: @emreozdemir Thanks for the suggestion. It's taking roughly the same time as before. I am doing a batch for each user, not a batch for the whole 5000 of them.

Comment: It makes sense to do this for each user. So the update itself consumes time i guess. Another thing is you can add index for "LOWER(column)" for migration, and drop the index afterwards ?

Comment: @emreozdemir The index creation itself takes too long. I am gonna edit my question with a different approach I have been taking.

Comment: Can you tell, updating using id's with your aproach, a single update takes how much time ? And you said 5000 users with 67 different tables, how you come up with millions of updates, a single table contains multiple rows with the same "column" value ?

Comment: Sure. Each user may appear multiple times each table. For example, Jira has a "worklog" table that currently results in 133441 update queries to migrate. The time it takes depends on the table. This same "worklog" table I mentioned takes 60 ms for each query, ran using PgAdmin.

Comment: @emreozdemir My app logs the execution times. This particular table took 105 minutes to execute 133441 updates. (In a single thread, and 9 other threads running updates on other tables). That is 21 updates each minute, or 1 update every 3 seconds.